# How to create linux terminal for a website where people could run linux commands and see output?

Tags: html, linux, web

I am working on a project where I want to create linux terminal like in geeksforgeeks we have terminal where we can code in C, C++, Java etc. Something similar to that but for linux. But I can't figure out how to do that. Can anyone give me a clear idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had developed kind of same portfolio in cli visit http://oswalgopal.github.io/cli

I is developed using https://xtermjs.org/.
I am running commands locally setted up the output but if you want to run all linux command then you need a linux server and develop a api in whatever you prefer and which will take the input which entered by user and return the output it got from server.

Comment: Thanks for replying!! Will this link (https://dev.to/saisandeepvaddi/how-to-create-web-based-terminals-38d) help me achieve what you have created? I mean have you created this with electron as mentioned in the article or socket.io?

Comment: yes It will. It is doing same as I said. electronJs is also a js library so you can add xtermJs